# Why does not it show the result of the foreach?

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I have the following query in my model

```
public function buscar_horario($date_start, $date_end, $rut_usu){

 $query = $this->db->query("select * from (
 SELECT  hrs_ini ,hrs_ter , lunes, martes, miercoles, jueves, viernes, sabado,
 fecha_registro, id_hr
 FROM horario
 INNER JOIN usuarios ON horario.rut_usu = usuarios.rut_usu
 WHERE usuarios.rut_usu= '$rut_usu' AND date(horario.fecha_ini) BETWEEN date('$date_start') AND date('$date_end') AND 
 fecha_registro = (SELECT MAX(fecha_registro) FROM horario where rut_usu = '$rut_usu' ) ORDER BY id_hr DESC LIMIT 14
 ) tmp order by tmp.id_hr asc  ");

 return $query;

}
```

The result I want to show in another view, so the controller is done in this way

```
public function buscar_horario(){

$rut_usu = $this->input->get('rut_usu');
$date_start = $this->input->get('date_start');
$date_end = $this->input->get('date_end');

$data['query'] = $this->M_Consultar_Horarios->buscar_horario($rut_usu,$date_start, $date_end);
$this->load->view('usuarios/consultar_horario.php',$data);

}
```

In the view, I am showing it by means of a foreach, but it does not show the result, if I execute the query with the same parameters in my database, it is displayed correctly.

```
foreach($query->result_array() as $row){

$html .= '<tr>
      <td style=" background-color:#f2f2f2;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; '.$row->hrs_ini.'</td>
      <td style="text-align:center; background-color:#f2f2f2;">'.$row->hrs_ter.'</td>
      <td style="text-align:center; background-color:#f2f2f2;">'.$row->lunes.' </td>
      <td style="text-align:center; background-color:#f2f2f2;">'.$row->martes.' </td>
      <td style="text-align:center; background-color:#f2f2f2;">'.$row->miercoles.' </td>
      <td style="text-align:center; background-color:#f2f2f2;">'.$row->jueves.' </td>
      <td style="text-align:center; background-color:#f2f2f2;">'.$row->viernes.' </td>
      <td style="text-align:center; background-color:#f2f2f2;">'.$row->sabado.' </td>
      </tr>'; }
```

The search parameters are passing correctly, because I am printing them in the result view

Comment: What are you doing with `$html`? So far you are not printing anything.

Comment: If you want the last block of code to print your rows, then replace `$html .= ` with `echo `. That should print it out as it loops through the results.

Comment: The foreach is in the html (I'm using a library to show it as pdf, that's why the variable $ html, this I have done successfully before using a different form of codeigniter query, using $ this-> db-> select blablabla.) But this way it does not show results, so I thought that I need to add something to the model query

Comment: It would also be useful to do it in this way, I think, that would give a good result $this->db->select(), $this->db->from() but I do not know how the query should be, since the tmp throws me a syntax error is what I try

Comment: `result_array()` obviously returns __array__. Accessing array elements is done with `[]`, not `->`.

Comment: if you are using result_array(), it returns an associative array i.e $row['lunes']. If you want to use $row->lunes you must use result() instead as it returns an object.

Comment: even if I change it result (), instead of result_array(); does not show anything: C

Comment: This has already been asked but where do you echo $html; ? And what if you do some simple debugging by adding in an echo "I am here at ".__LINE__; before and after the foreach etc so you can see if the code is even being reached/used etc.

Answer (score 0):

to fix your approach you need to define $html before the foreach loop:

```
<?php
  $html='';
  foreach($query->result_array() as $row){   
    $html .= '<tr>
                <td style=" background-color:#f2f2f2;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; '.$row->hrs_ini.'</td>
              // etc...
             </tr>'; 
  }
?>
```

and output it like this:

```
<?php
  echo $html;
?>
```